# Javascript Size Controls not working in Child Page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

I'm trying to add a Master page to existing pages to create a site-wide header. Unfortunately, some Javascript size controls stop working when I add a master page reference to the Default.aspx

```
function ChangePanelHeight(){
    var MyPanel;
    var NewHeight=(screen.height*.45);
    MyPanel = document.getElementById('pnlContainer');
    MyPanel.style.height = NewHeight + "px";
}
```

That javascript function (which is embedded on the content page) works when I add the master page, but the resizing does not. In other words, an `alert('Hey!');` within the javascript triggers just fine, but for some reason the panel height remains unchanged. It works fine without it. The master page looks like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Site.master.vb"  Inherits="PropertyManagementSystem.Site" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="header">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><h1>Property Management System</h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h2>All Your Property - Managed At The Palm Of Your Hand</h2></td>
        <td><h2>Welcome <asp:Label ID="lblWhoName" runat="server"/></h2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a id="lHome" href="Default.aspx">Home</a></td>
        <td><a id="lManageDevices" href="ManageDevices.aspx">Manage Devices</a></td>
        <td><a id="lManageLookupTables" href="ManageLookups.aspx">Manage Lookups</a></td>
        <td><a id="lHelp" href="Help.aspx">Help</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (making the element ID of .getElementID refer to the client ID of the control):

```
function ChangePanelHeight(){
    var MyPanel;
    var NewHeight=(screen.height*.45);
    MyPanel = document.getElementById('<%=pnlContainer.ClientID %>');
    MyPanel.style.height = NewHeight + "px";
}
```

Comment: I can't remember if you need the single quotes for that or not

Comment: Thanks! You helped me find the answer. Apparently "ct100_MainContent_" is appended to the front of the ID when it's rendered client-side, so your answer was along the right track.

Comment: No problem! Yeah it's a bit of a pain, had this issue myself recently. It's appended client-side whenever controls are children to a parent control, the 'ClientID' of a control will always refer to that complete string though.